# SQL запрос с объединением

Tags: sql

Итак. Есть 3 таблицы. products, sku и sort_products. Я объединяю первые две через JOIN и тут все хорошо. Но Поскольку каждый product может иметь несколько sku, то делая JOIN с sku я логично получаю тонны дублей товаров, тк на каждый sku он берет инфу из products. Я же хочу иметь таблицу вида product.id и sku (где все возможные sku для этого товара представлены в виде строки). Вот текущий код с этой проблемой:

```
SELECT products.id, products.category_id, products.name, sku.sku FROM products
INNER JOIN sort_products ON products.id = sort_products.product_id
LEFT JOIN sku ON sku.product_id = products.id
WHERE products.category_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15)
ORDER BY sort_position LIMIT 100;
```

Помогите переписать правильно

Comment: Какой диалект SQL? Посмотри возможность использования функций ARRAY_AGG, LIST_AGG

Comment: @TimurTrotsky на MySQL строю запрос

Comment: В mysql это называется group_concat

Comment: У вас путаница в терминологии. JOIN - это соединение, а объединение - это UNION